# Clicking on a specific spot on an HTML5 Video in Chrome

Tags: html5-video, playback

I have an MP4 video (76MB) that I am playing from our server using the standard HTML5  tag. In Chrome, the video doesn't allow me to move forward or back by clicking on the timeline or moving the positional thumb.

I have reviewed other videos on our server and found the same issue. I can jump to specific spots in the video in both Firefox and Edge, but not in Chrome.

This is the video in question: https://www.primary-intel.com/demos/helping-sales-reps/

I want to be able to click anywhere in the timeline at any time in Chrome to move to a different part of the video.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: very odd behaviour, I can only assume some server or CloudFlare configuration as if I grab a video and host it locally it behaves exactly as expected

Comment: It must be, @Offbeatmammal. I uploaded the video to a different server and linked to it from there and am not having the same problems. I have reached out to my host company to see if there is a setting that can be tweaked to fix this.